# storing pdf files on amazon s3 using itext

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, itext

This is my first time using amazon s3 and I want to store pdf files that I create using itext in java spring.

The code (hosted on ec2 instance) creates a pdf that I would like to store somewhere. I am exploring if amazon s3 can hold those files. Eventually I would like to retrieve it as well. Can this be done using itext and java spring? Any examples would be great.

Comment: just using java you can do this move your file into S3

Comment: Google? :) https://javatutorial.net/java-s3-example or http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Upload Files to Amazon s3 You need to use `putObject` method of AmazonS3Client class like this:

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(appId,appSecret);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

    String bucketPath = "YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_INSIDE_BUCKET";
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("YOUR_PDF_FILE_PATH");
    ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
    meta.setContentLength(is.available());
    s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketPath,"YOUR_FILE.pdf", is, meta).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.Private));
```

And to get file from S3, You need to generate a pre-signed URL to access private file from S3 or if your files are public then you can directly access your file by hitting link of file in your browser, The link for your file will be available in AWS S3 console.

Also we have specified `CannedAccessControlList.Private` in the above upload code which means we are making permission of file as private So we need to generate presigned URL to access file like this:

```
  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(appId,appSecret);
  AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

  GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("YOUR_BUCKET_NAME", "FOLDER_INSIDE_BUCKET/YOUR_FILE.pdf");

  generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); 

  Date expiration = new Date();
  long milliSeconds = expiration.getTime();
  milliSeconds += 1000 * 60 * 60; // Add 1 hour.
  expiration.setTime(milliSeconds);
  generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);
  URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest); 
  String finalUrl  = url.toString();
```

Comment: Work like a charm..  :)